# When and how is DragDetect useful?

Tags: c++, mfc, drag-and-drop

Basically I need something to determine if the user in the process of a drag and drop action to determine when to suppress over zealous default behavior of the `CTreeCtrl` label editing in an extended multi-select tree control.

[`CWnd::DragDetect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f8tya8a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) returns true when the user has moved the mouse outside of a defined rect with the left button down.  I was thinking of using the return value of this in `::OnMouseMove` to determine if a drag operation is in progress to enable or disable certain GUI effects and actions.

Sounds all well and good but does this really accomplish anything more than taking the same mouse point and simply doing a hit test with the selected item?  I already have to do a hit test for drop targets anyway so it seems like a wholly unnecessary method.

Google didn't turn up any examples of using this method and SO also returned no results so I'm curious when and if this is ever a useful method or if this is not the intended use.

Has anyone used this before?

Comment: Is `Math.Sqrt()` a wholly unnecessary method because you can implement Newton-Raphson yourself?

Comment: @Anon point taken ... however this seems to be more akin to having length() in addition to size() on std::string unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The size of the rectangle for DragDetect is not necessarily the same as the size of the object you're dragging. It's like having both a method to get the number of characters in a string, and one to get the number of bytes the characters occupy.

Comment: I've found that using DragDetect in the LButtonDown handler causes LButtonUp messages to get eaten ... apparently a side effect is the majority of the CTreeCtrl mouse events will be handled by the parent window after making a call to this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intent is to call `DragDetect` from your `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` handler to see if the user is trying to drag something from your application. If it returns true, this is the start of a drag operation; if it's false, then not. After a return of true you start tracking the mouse and doing hit tests to provide feedback, if any; you should at least change the cursor at this point. Finally at `WM_LBUTTONUP` you do a final hit test to see what the drop target is.

Comment: So this is more useful when detecting a drag and drop operation between windows? Otherwise isn't TVN_BEGINDRAG message and the hit tests sufficient?

Comment: @AJG85, within a window or between windows doesn't make any difference, as long as you've captured the mouse. TVN_BEGINDRAG is specific to tree controls while DragDetect works for any window.

Comment: Ah yes that would be useful my particular usage is only within the context of a tree control so that's where the curiosity came from.

Comment: How does dragDetect work internally? Does it pause execution for X amount of time to sample the mouse position?

Comment: @MatiasChara that's a very good question.  I'm afraid I don't know the answer.

Comment: @MatiasChara I see you've asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63060714/5987), good for you - that's exactly how the system is supposed to work.