# Brief explanation for WM_LBUTTONDOWN windows message and DragDetect

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a very simple question regarding this snippet(part of windows message handling in a larger switch structure that is irrelevant.):

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        POINT pt = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
        if (DragDetect(m_hwnd, pt))
        {
            OutputDebugStringW(L"drag detected!!!");
        }
        return 0;
```

Does "DragDetect" pause execution of the program for the time it takes to sample mouse input to determine if the mouse was dragged? If its the case, wouldn`t it be bad for performance?

Comment: @drescherjm what it does isn't in question.  The question is whether any other part of your code is able to execute while `DragDetect` is waiting to make a determination.

Comment: As far as being bad for performance, does it matter?  The most important thing for a GUI program to do is to respond to user input, and the user holding down the left mouse button is pretty important input.  What else would you be trying to do in the meantime?

Comment: @MarkRansom I mean, if every time the user clicks, with the left mouse button in this case, there is going to be a small sampling delay to check if the mouse is dragging, then it could hurt highly interactive programs that require high responsiveness.

Comment: But `DragDetect` will end as soon as the left mouse button goes up, so I don't understand how it would affect responsiveness.  Sorry to be so argumentative, I really do want to understand your concern.

Comment: It is not really I concern I have, im just curious as to how it works, thats it.

Comment: @MatiasChara the easiest way to determine that is to simply try it and see what happens.

Comment: @rem You cannot observe the unobservable. `DragDetect` may be a blocking call, but there's not way to know, what happens inside that call. It's reasonable to *assume*, that it spins up its own modal message loop, which opens up re-entrancy opportunities for posted, generated, as well as cross-thread sent messages. It's likewise reasonable to want to know about those re-entrancy opportunities by reading the documented contract. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dragdetect) doesn't offer answers.

Comment: @IInspectable "*Does "DragDetect" **pause execution of the program** for the time it takes to sample mouse input to determine if the mouse was dragged?*" - that is an easily-observable effect.  Either the whole program is paused (no messages are dispatched/processed), or it is not paused (because it runs a secondary modal loop, etc).

Comment: @rem Is it, though? What, if `DragDetect` does indeed run its own modal message loop, but won't let any messages escape? Does that count as *"paused"*, because everything outside `DragDetect` doesn't get an opportunity to run, or as *"not paused"*, because the part of the program concerned with drag detection is able to make forward progress?

Comment: A *very* similar thing happens when you drag an edge of the window.  A modal message loop inside the OS now dispatches messages, intercepting the mouse move messages to resize the window.  Such message loops are common, nobody worries about perf unless they make their own message loop do too much.

Comment: [Dragging UI Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/other-mouse-operations#dragging-ui-elements):  do not call `DragDetect` unless your program is currently in a mode that supports dragging.  Each api call takes some time, even if we do not feel the delay.